# CASE / IF Statement to declare variable based on parameter value

Tags: sql, if-statement, parameters, case

Been researching 'CASE' syntax and I think I'm close to getting what I need here but something is off. SSMS didn't like the way I wrote my query with CASE and I ended up confusing myself so I've written the sample below as if it were an 'IF' statement just so I can express what I'm trying to achieve. Any hints or tips would certainly be appreciated.

The goal is to have a parameter list of date ranges ("Last Week", "Month to Date", etc) that when selected will pass two values (upper and lower date limits) to the WHERE statement.

```
DECLARE @Param1 VARCHAR(20)
-- Param1 will be set when the user selects a string value, e.g. "Last Month"

DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
-- Date1 & Date2 will be the respective lower and upper date boundaries used in the WHERE statement.

IF @Param1 = 'Last Month'
THEN
SET @Date1 = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())))
SET @Date2 = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,GETDATE()))

ELSE IF @Param1 = 'Current Month'
THEN
SET @Date1 = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,GETDATE()))
SET @Date2 = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())

ELSE
-- Default to yesterday if nothing selected by user
SET @Date1 = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-1)
SET @Date2 = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())

END IF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this with two `case` statements:

```
select @Date1 = (case when @Param1 = 'Last Month'
                      then CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())))
                      when @Param1 = 'Current Month'
                      then CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,GETDATE()))
                      else CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-1)
                  end);

select @Date2 = (case when @Param1 = 'Last Month'
                      then CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,GETDATE()))
                      when @Param1 = 'Current Month'
                      then CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
                      else CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
                  end);
```